# JPA : Transaction rollback not working

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, rollback

My code is actually huge, so well here's the code. 
I try to store the streams of a set of files into the database in one transaction and that transaction is committed.

Soon after I use the same transaction rewrite the file streams in the database and other data along with it. So I begin the same transaction again and commit it after this process is complete. But in case of exceptions the transaction is not rolled back and the database is updated with the new values. What could be the cause of this?

Please help and thanks in advance.

```
try {
            Map<String, String> constants = AppConstants.getAppConstants();
            String hrEmailIds = constants.get(FileUploadDownloadConstants.HR_EMAIL);

            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            fileDao.setEmployeekeychangestatus(employeeID, KeyChangeJobStatus.STARTED.getValue());
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            entityManager.flush();

            setOldFileStreams(employeeID);

            List <Integer>tempFileIds = fileDao.getTempFileIds(employeeID);
            entityManager.clear();

            KeyPair keyPair = cryptographyHelper.getKeyPairs();
            PublicKey newPublicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
            PrivateKey newPrivateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
            PrivateKey oldPrivateKey = job.getPrivateKey();
            Tempfile tempFile;
            ByteArrayOutputStream fileEncryptedWithNewKey;

            for(int tempFileId : tempFileIds)
            {
                tempFile = fileDao.getTempFileById(tempFileId);
                fileEncryptedWithNewKey = decryptAndEncryptStream(tempFile, oldPrivateKey, newPublicKey);

                absolutePath = tempFile.getFilemetadata().getFilepath();
                path = absolutePath.substring(0,absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
                fileDao.storeFile(fileEncryptedWithNewKey, path, tempFile.getFilemetadata().getFilename());
                fileCompletionCount++;
                fileEncryptedWithNewKey.close();
                entityManager.clear();

                intkeyChangeProgress = findPercentage(fileCompletionCount,numberOfFiles,FileUploadDownloadConstants.PRECENTAGE_TO_UPDATE_FILE_STREAM);
                intkeyChangeProgress += FileUploadDownloadConstants.PRECENTAGE_TO_SET_OLD_FILE_STREAMS;
                EmployeeOperationStatus.putEmployeeKeyChangeProgress(employeeID,intkeyChangeProgress);
            }

            intkeyChangeProgress = findPercentage(fileCompletionCount,numberOfFiles,FileUploadDownloadConstants.PRECENTAGE_TO_UPDATE_FILE_STREAM);
            intkeyChangeProgress += FileUploadDownloadConstants.PRECENTAGE_TO_SET_OLD_FILE_STREAMS;
            EmployeeOperationStatus.putEmployeeKeyChangeProgress(employeeID,intkeyChangeProgress);

            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

            fileDao.deleteTempFilesForEmployee(employeeID);


            ByteArrayOutputStream byteEncryptedPrvateKey = encryptKey(employeeID, newPrivateKey);
            constants = AppConstants.getAppConstants();
            String privateKeyPath = constants.get(FileUploadDownloadConstants.BASE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH);

            employee = fileDao.getEmployee(employeeID);
            keyDao.updatePublicKey(employee, newPublicKey);

            fileDao.removeEmployeekeychangestatus(employeeID);

            fileDao.storeFile(byteEncryptedPrvateKey, privateKeyPath, employee.getUserid()+FileUploadDownloadConstants.PRIVATE_KEY_EXTENSION);
            privateKeyByteArray = cryptographyHelper.getPrivateKeyBytes(newPrivateKey);
            mailingService.sendMailForKeyNotification(employee.getEmail(), hrEmailIds, privateKeyByteArray, 
                    employee.getUserid()+FileUploadDownloadConstants.PRIVATE_KEY_EXTENSION, FileUploadDownloadConstants.CHANGE_KEY);

            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            entityManager.clear();

        } catch (EmprisException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();

        } catch (Exception e ) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have open two separate transaction.
When the second transaction raises an exception, the first exception is not rollbacked, it's already committed.

Comment: Actually here the second transaction is not getting rolled back when I get an exception in the second transaction block

Comment: Could you post some stacktraces?

Comment: Actually the stacktrace is not at all related to entity manager. I produced this scenario by changing value of a field in the database.